# Install modules with perlbrew and cpm - perlbrew switch does not change @INC during docker build

Tags: perl, docker, perlbrew, cpanm

I'd like to use fast [cpm](https://github.com/skaji/cpm) module installer instead of cpanm in my projects.

Also I install target perl version using [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/).

According [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpm::Tutorial#First-step) of cpm `-g` option will install modules into current @INC

How to force perlbrew change @INC in Dockerfile ?

Below is part of my Dockerfile

```
RUN perl -le 'print for @INC' && \
    perlbrew switch perl-5.31.0 && \
    perl -le 'print for @INC' && \
    cpm install -gv CGI && \
    perlbrew list-modules
```

When I build Dockerfile output of `perl -le 'print for @INC'` is same both times:

```
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
/usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

But if I do same manually result is ok:

```
$ docker run -it pavelsr/xxxhub
root@1a34ea34a3fb:/# perl -le 'print for @INC'
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22
/usr/share/perl/5.22
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
.
root@1a34ea34a3fb:/# perlbrew switch perl-5.31.0

A sub-shell is launched with perl-5.31.0 as the activated perl. Run 'exit' to finish it.

root@1a34ea34a3fb:/# perl -le 'print for @INC'
/usr/local/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.31.0/lib/site_perl/5.31.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.31.0/lib/site_perl/5.31.0
/usr/local/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.31.0/lib/5.31.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.31.0/lib/5.31.0
root@1a34ea34a3fb:/# cpm install -g CGI
DONE install HTML-Tagset-3.20
DONE install HTML-Parser-3.72
DONE install CGI-4.44
3 distributions installed.
root@1a34ea34a3fb:/# perlbrew list-modules
CGI
HTML::Parser
HTML::Tagset
Perl
```

Comment: Re "*A sub-shell is launched with*", Well, for starters, you didn't add `source "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/etc/bashrc` to `.bashrc` as instructed. `perlbrew use` and `perlbrew switch` simply manipulate the `PATH`. To be able to do this, the sourced script creates a function named `perlbrew` in the shell. As a fallback for when these functions are missing, there's a script called `perlbrew` too. The script obviously can't change the `PATH` of the shell that called it, so it launches a subshell with the fixed up `PATH` instead.

Comment: So, without the functions, your pipeline can't possibly be affected by `perlbrew switch`. Start by fixing this.

Comment: Re "*How to force perlbrew change @INC in Dockerfile ?*", Despite repeated statements that claim you want to change `@INC`, that's not what you want to do. You actually want to change which install of `perl` is being used.

Comment: @ikegami thanks you so much for that detailed explanation. But I don't undertand how and when perlbrew fix `$PATH`. I tried to print `$PATH` before and after `RUN echo 'source "${PERLBREW_ROOT}"/etc/bashrc' >> .bashrc`, step, it wasn't changed and is `/usr/local/perlbrew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` in both cases.

Comment: For now, I just directly set `PATH` in `Dockerfile`: `ENV PATH ${PERLBREW_ROOT}/perls/perl-$PERL_VERSION/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, "*A sub-shell is launched with ...*" indicates you have an incorrectly setup `perlbrew`. You were instructed to add the following to your shell's startup script:

```
source "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/etc/bashrc
```

Without this, a fallback mechanism is used to try to provide the desired functionality, but it's completely useless outside of interactive shells.

---

Secondly, this is a rather dubious use of perlbrew. If your docker script worked as intended, it would have far reaching consequences. That's not a good thing. You could use `perlbrew use`, but you could instead use the correct `perl` build directly using

```
RUN "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/perls/perl-5.31.0/bin/perl -S cpm install -gv CGI
```

In your case, this should resolve to

```
RUN /usr/local/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.31.0/bin/perl -S cpm install -gv CGI
```

for you.

Comment: `RUN ${PERLBREW_ROOT}/perls/perl-$PERL_VERSION/bin/perl --version` shows correct version, but `RUN ${PERLBREW_ROOT}/perls/perl-$PERL_VERSION/bin/perl cpm install -gv CGI && perlbrew list-modules` will produce `Can't open perl script "cpm": No such file or directory` error.

Comment: Oh sorry, provide the full path to `cpm` or use `.../perl -S cpm ...`. (`-S` tell Perl search the path for the script.) Fixed.